# export 'default' (imported as 'FontAwesomeIcon') was not found in '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome' (possible exports: FontAwesomeIcon)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, sass, icons

I downloaded fontawesome icons on vs code terminal with "npm i @fortawesome/react-fontawesome"
and then other free solid and brands svg icons like this "npm i @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons"; "npm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons". Then when I wrote code with this icon, it shows me an error((.

`import './index.scss'
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faHome } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const SideBar = () => {

```
    <nav>
        <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" to="/">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} color="#4d4" />
        </NavLink>
    </nav>
</div>
```

}

export default SideBar
`

Answer (score 2):

The FontAwesomeIcon is not exported as default. You can import it with brackets around it.

import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";